# Search for exe file within a condition

Tags: file, bash, shell, directory, executable

I want to search for all .exe files greater than 200 kB or smaller than 120 kB in the current folder and its subfolders. Then I want to move them to another folder called "folder" and execute in this folder the file called "executable.exe" infinitely and show some information about its memory consumption.

Any ideas?

Comment: Linux and Unix don't typically have ".exe" files. Are you using Bash in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a gnu-ish `find` (not sure what mingw uses), something like this?

```
cd your_folder

find . -name '*.exe' \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \) -exec mv {} folder \;

cd folder

run_some_executable.exe
```

The `find` finds your files, exec's a move of each one to your folder.

Then it cd's to your folder and runs the executable.

You'd then have to run another tool to check memory consumption.

Comment: `echo foo {} baz` moves files to folder?

Comment: what do you mean by echo foo {} baz !

Comment: 1000 pardons; you are all correct; that was an artifact of me testing out the solution locally without actually doing a move.  I've edited the answer.  mea culpa!